# How to create columns for data in the output ?

Tags: python

```
 def onNewData(self, data):
    zvalues = []
    f = open("rawdata.txt","w+")
    for i in range(data.getNumPoints()):
        zvalues.append(data.getZ(i))
        f.write((str(data.getX(i))+',')+(str(data.getY(i))+',') + (str(data.getZ(i))+',')+(str(data.getNoise(i))+',')+(str(data.getGrayValue(i))+',') + (str(data.getDepthConfidence(i))+','))
        if (i+1)%224==0:    
            f.write('\n') 
    f.close()
```

For this set of code, the text document output shows all the numbers being jumbled up without any format. How do i make the number fall respectively under each category in column format ? For example i have a header of x , y , z , grayvalue , Noise , DepthConfidence and the numbers will fall accordingly under each category.

[Output of the text document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1wfr.png)

Comment: This code snippet is not complete--what are the definitions of `getZ()`, `getX()`, etc.? What data types do they return? Why does your code print 224 groups of data on one line? (You would get closer to what you want simply by removing the `if (i+1)%224==0` line.) By "column format" do you mean that you want the values to line up in columns? Are the columns to be left-, right-, decimal-, or center-justified? How many rows do you expect to get--is it reasonable to store all strings in the entire table before printing any? Your question needs more details before a good answer can be given.

Comment: getZ() , getX() etc is to get the data points of an object that is going to be captured. yes, column format means that i want the values to line up in columns and the i want the column to be on the left. I expect to get 6 rows and it is reasonable to store all strings in the entire table before printing.  Sorry for the lack of details as i am a newbie inside stackoverflow

Comment: Your question is "How do I format data as a table?", correct? Using that as search terms might yield existing answers. Without that, it isn't really clear what you have and what you want, include examples in the question itself (external links are bad because they may change with time). As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm to print your data into left-justified columns. First, get all the data in its string representation into an array. Each row of the array will be a row of printed data, and each column is to be a printed column. Then for each column, find and store the maximum length of the data items in that column. Then loop over the rows of the array. For each row and for each column in that row, print or write the data item and add enough spaces so the data item takes the same space as the largest data item in that column. Remember to print/write an end-of-line at the end of each row.

You still have a few decisions to make, such as whether you put the separator commas before or after the padding spaces. But here is some possible code.

```
# Get the data in string format into an array
toprint = []
for i in range(data.getNumPoints()):
    toprint.append([str(data.getX(i)),
                    str(data.getY(i)),
                    str(data.getZ(i)),
                    str(data.getNoise(i)),
                    str(data.getGrayValue(i)),
                    str(data.getDepthConfidence(i)),
    ])

# Get the maximum size data for each column
numrows = len(toprint)
numcols = len(toprint[0])
maxwidths = [max(len(toprint[rownum][colnum]) 
             for rownum in range(numrows))
             for colnum in range(numcols)]

# Print the data left-justified
for row in toprint:
    printrow = ', '.join(s.ljust(maxwidths[colnum]) for s in row)
    print(printrow, file=f)
```

You did not give enough data in text format for me to test that code.